# "expert level knowledge in something" or "expert level of knowledge in something", which one is right?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

If I want to express having expert level of skills, can I say "expert level knowledge in something" or "expert knowledge in something"? Which one is right in the context of resume?

Comment: Yes, and I suggest you check out all the online resumes out there...

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use them but if you are to have it in resume, the better composition (and common as well) is -

> *...have expertise **in** something"

Check [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/expertise) on Cambridge-

> *She has considerable **expertise in** French history.*